# document.documentElement.innerHTML not current when retrieved

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm trying to retrieve the current page's HTML within a Tampermonkey script via

```
let currentPageSource = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

which works fine the first time the code is triggered but when the page changes and that code is hit again the information I get in the variable doesn't change from the first time.

I'm guessing it's something obvious I'm missing but it's driving me mad.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML)`? Not sure of the context here but if you trying to redeclare `currentPageSource` in the same scope that won't work. You could just access `document.documentElement.innerHTML` directly without storing in a variable if you don't need to access it a bunch of times.